# Execute View of a controller that is inside a folder MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Im having problem guys. I have some controllers that are inside a folder but i dont know how to execute the View.

Example

```
Proyect
    /Controller
        /LBBANK
           /LBBANKController
```

I need the view of the last controller but how?

I tried this

```
@Url.Action("Index","LBBANK/LBBANK")
```

But it doesnot work. What can i do?

Comment: You should use areas instead.

Comment: It that the only solution?

Comment: You can also just ignore the folder.

Comment: uuuuhh! It worked! thnks!